# document.getElementById doesn’t work

Tags: javascript

If I write code 2 *without* code 1, the code works and it shows me “aaaaa”.

But if I write code 1 *and* code 2, the code doesn’t work. Instead of showing me “vvvaa”, it doesn’t show me anything (not “aaaaa” and not “vvvaa”).

Why doesn’t it work? (The `document.getElementById` doesn’t send the information to the `<div>`.)

**Code 1:**

```js
document.getElementById('na').innerHTML = "vvvaa";
```

**Code 2:**

```js
document.write("<div id='na'> aaaaa </div>");
```

**Complete Code:** *(the only thing on the page)*

```html
<script>
    function timeago(time) {
        var new_date = new Date();
        var time_ago = Math.floor(new_date.getTime()/1000-time);
        var d = Math.floor(time_ago/24/60/60);
        var h = Math.floor((time_ago-d*24/60/60)/60/60);        
        var m = Math.floor((time_ago-d*24/60/60-h*60/60)/60);
        var s = Math.floor(time_ago-d*24/60/60-h*60/60-m*60);
        document.write(d+"d - "+h+"h - "+m+"m - "+s+"s");
        document.getElementById('na').innerHTML="vvvaa";
        // setTimeout( function(){ timeago(time); }, 2000 ); 
    }
    timeago('1376743609');
    document.write("<div id='na'> aaaaa </div>");
</script>
```

Comment: What's your problem dude? How can we help you?

Comment: wrong order, 1 cannot possibly work before 2 because it depends on content created by 2

Comment: @AliGajani why the code 1 didnt send the "vvvaa" to the DIV?

Comment: The div must exist before you can make changes on it

Comment: @Idoroni: Answer given below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order matters. You cannot access your element `'na'` before having it in the document.

You naturally need to add the element to the document first. If that's done, you can access it by functions like `getElementById()`.

This...

```
document.write("<div id='na'></div>");
document.getElementById('na').innerHTML = "vvvaa";
```

... will work.

You may shortcut this to:

```
document.write("<div id='na'>vvvaa</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your console says that `document.getElementById('na')` is undefined and `innerHTML` is not a method of undefined. This is caused by the fact that there is no such element when the code is called. A fatal error will stop any further javascript execution, in this case your `document.write`.

Add the element to your document first before trying to access it via `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a piece of text unless it really does exist. In your case, you are trying to access the text when it doesn't even exist at that point. The order matters. Code 2 should go first and Code 1 should go last. First write the text, then access it.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.write` only be passed after `timeago()` therefore does not exist over the `<div>`, so just call "timerago" after using `document.write` Try:

```
<script>
function timeago(time) {
    var new_date = new Date();
    var time_ago = Math.floor(new_date.getTime()/1000-time);
    var d = Math.floor(time_ago/24/60/60);
    var h = Math.floor((time_ago-d*24/60/60)/60/60);        
    var m = Math.floor((time_ago-d*24/60/60-h*60/60)/60);
    var s = Math.floor(time_ago-d*24/60/60-h*60/60-m*60);
    document.write(d+"d - "+h+"h - "+m+"m - "+s+"s");
    document.getElementById('na').innerHTML="vvvaa";
    // setTimeout( function(){ timeago(time); }, 2000 ); 
}
document.write("<div id='na'> aaaaa </div>");
timeago('1376743609');
</script>
```